# Deployment of application to device failed

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm developing a WindowsPhone8 application on Visual Studio 2012.3. (on Windows8 x64, ARM project) Application works fine on emulator, but when I tried to deploy it onto real phone I have got:

Windows Phone: Deployment of application to device failed.

Comment: [see this knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784836)

Comment: It is a very strange solution from Microsoft. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common question. I think that it will be helpful:

> "The current implementation of strong names in Windows Phone 8 does
>   not support the RSA-SHA256, RSA-SHA384, or RSA-SHA512 (collectively
>   known as RSA-SHA2) signature algorithms. The current implementation
>   supports only the RSA-SHA1 signature algorithm. Therefore, developers
>   should use the RSA-SHA1 signature algorithm. Developers who write
>   Portable Class Library projects that include Windows Phone 8 as one of
>   the target platforms should consider this support if they decide to
>   sign their projects. "